# Empty EditText return string into name, id

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to get the string of the EditText and if it is " I want to get "  also but the string is appearing this in the EditText

```
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText{42e33310 VFED..CL .F ....ID40,40-1160,315 #7f0c006f app:id\CalculatorDisplay}
```

after getting it and giving it to the EditText again
and here is a part of the onClick that works when I press a button and the rest of it is not dealing with this problem the problem is in NoRepeatNumber as I tested that when I get it in TestTV TextView I saw the code above

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    TestTV.setText("enterd ");
    String buttonPressed = ((Button) view).getText().toString();
    PublicButtonPressed = buttonPressed;
    if (DIGITS.contains(buttonPressed)) {
        SinOrNumber=2;
        TestTV.append("numbering");
        // digit was pressed

        if (!Started) {
            mCalculatorDisplay.setText("");
            TestTV.append("\nenterd setText");
        } else {
            TestTV.append("\nenterd setText eslse");
        }

        if (Started) {
            OperationEnded = true;
        }
        if (NumberingEnded) {
            FullNumber = String.valueOf(Number[Ni]);
            Ni++;
            NumberingEnded = false;
            FullCalculation= FullNumber + " ";
            NoRepeatNumber="";
            DisplayCalculations();
        }
        FullNumber = FullNumber + buttonPressed;
        Number[Ni] = Integer.parseInt(FullNumber);
        TestTV.append("\nNumber[" + Ni + "] =" + + Number[Ni] + "\n" + "buttonPressed =" + buttonPressed + "\nFullNumber =" + FullNumber);
        //DisplayCalculations();
        if ("".equals(mCalculatorDisplay)) {

            TestTV.append("\nentered equal\"\"");

            NoRepeatNumber="";
        } else {
            if (NoRepeatNumber == "") {
                NoRepeatNumber = String.valueOf(mCalculatorDisplay);
                TestTV.append("\nNoRepeatNumber =" + NoRepeatNumber);
            }
        }
        if(!NumberingEnded){
            mCalculatorDisplay.setText(NoRepeatNumber + FullNumber);
        }

        if (!Started) {
            Started = true;
        }
        if (userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber) {

            if (buttonPressed.equals(".") && mCalculatorDisplay.getText().toString().contains(".")) {
                // ERROR PREVENTION
                // Eliminate entering multiple decimals
            } else {
                Number[Ni] = Integer.parseInt(FullNumber);
            }
        }
        userIsInTheMiddleOfTypingANumber = true;
    } else {}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `mCalculatorDisplay.getText().toString()` instead of `String.valueOf(mCalculatorDisplay)`.

I guess mCalculatorDisplay is an EditText?

Update:  `NoRepeatNumber = String.valueOf(mCalculatorDisplay);` - this is the problem part

Comment: yes mCalculatorDisplay is an EditText thanks for the solution thats works but will you explaine more about the different between the two methodes

Comment: first method is the way you get a text from your EditText: editText.getText() returns object wrapper for your text. toString() on that wrapper returns the text in the form of String. 

Second method is a general method of a String class to get its string representation. Internally it calls the objects toString() method. You call this method on an EditText, whose toString() doesn't return the text, but some information about that EditText.